# Can't access site externally

Tags: apache-2.2

So i am trying to access my site using my ip address xx.xx.xxx.xx (don't think it's a good idea to give it out). But i get Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data. Here is what i have tried so far:

Made sure that the site works on localhost.
Forwarded port 80 on my router to my computer.
Checked canyouseeme.org to make sure port 80 is open on my computer, it works fine.
Tried to ping my computer ip address from work and it doesn't seem to work.
What am i doing wrong ? I recently reinstalled WAMP and it was working fine before, not sure what changed :-/ Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you state that it worked before (presumably from offsite) and the 324 error appears to be a clientside issue specific to Google Chrome, I would first try loading the site in a different browser(s). If you get the same results then confirm the details of the web servers socket with `netstat -noab|find /i "listen"|find /i ":80"`. I would want to rule out that the socket is not binding to 127.0.0.1:80 or something similar.

Comment: First off, thanks for your input. I tried different browsers but no luck. I ran the command you stated, here's what i got `TCP 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 908`

Comment: The netstat output looks good, did the other browsers give you the same error?

Comment: Firefox says `The connection was reset               
          `The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.`

Comment: OK, at this point I would scrutinize the router. First just try resetting the modem/router then if that yields nothing, you could save your router config settings then restore default settings, then configure your port-forwarding setup.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have another computer on the **same** network? If so, can that computer access your webserver? That's your first step, then worry about being visible to the outside world.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not at home right now, but i will try this suggesting when i do get home.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this on a consumer ISP line it is entirely possible that your ISP is blocking well-known ports to prevent you from running servers (which is undoubtedly against your Terms of Service).

ISPs generally are not terribly smart, though, and only block well known ports. I would try reconfiguring Apache to listen on some port other than 80 (like 81, or 8181), reconfigure your router to forward that port to your computer and try it again.

Comment: Why reconfigure Apache when OP said port 80 was visible via canyouseeme.org?

Comment: Because in some cases instead of outright blocking a port, the ISP will traffic shape to drop outgoing packets. In that case, a simple port scan will show the port as open, but you will not succeed in getting any traffic back on that port.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to try another browser other than Chrome to ensure that this isn't just a Google Chrome cache issue.

It doesn't look to be a firewall issue due to the fact it can be seen externally from canyouseeme.org.A quick google search of net::err_empty_response points to the fact that this is a Google Chrome issue and not necessarily a web server issues.

Comment: I tried it from firefox and ie too, no luck :-(